# How can I upload files to https://github.com/downloads/<user>/<repo>/?

Tags: github

I see people hosting files (usually binary files) under `https://github.com/downloads/<user>/<repository>/`. How do they do it?

Comment: Can you give an example of a URL like that? I haven't seen this before.

Comment: See for example [link](https://github.com/downloads/shaunsephton/holodeck/screenie.0.1.0.png) (no idea what that repo is, I just googled `"https://github.com/downloads/"` to find examples). The URL is actually a 302 redirection to a Github-owned S3 bucket.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't `https://github.com/<user>/<repository>/releases/download/` ?

Comment: @NicolasChristin - I wonder if that's an older endpoint. The readme that points to that link you provided was last edited in 2012.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. That doesn't exist anymore... GitHub used to have a [`Downloads` API that was replaced by the `Releases` API back in 2013](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/). Old links were redirected and still work as you can see on the example you provided in the comments.

Nowadays, if you want to make files available for download, you should use either the [Releases](https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/managing-releases-in-a-repository) feature or the [Packages](https://github.com/features/packages) feature.

[image: GitHub Releases, Tags, and Packages]

Comment: Thank you, you answered my question perfectly.